# JDBC connecting java to sql server database

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

```
 public Connection getConnection()throws Exception {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=PRJ311;integratedSecurity=true;";
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, userID, password);
}
```

So basically I have just installed ms sql server 2017 and I used default settings for developer. Do I need a username and password? And if it's needed, how can I get it? I have been googling the whole night so hopefully someone can help. Thanks!\n

P/s: My program is stuck and even though I use try-catch blocks, it prints out no error at all!
The connection name specified by sql server is: localhost\MSSQLSERVER01 (DESKTOP-TG6LRB4\emsnguyen)

Comment: *"Do I need a username and password?"* Not when using integrated security.

Comment: *"The connection name specified by sql server is: localhost\MSSQLSERVER01"* So why did you use `localhost:1433`? Port 1433 is used by the default unnamed instance. You have a named instance.

Comment: so what' the cause of the problem?

Comment: Because it doesn't work so I tried multiple solutions

Comment: Replace `localhost:1433` with `localhost\MSSQLSERVER01`. Remember to double the ``\\`` in a Java text literal.

Comment: *FYI:* `Class.forName` is not necessary anymore.

Comment: so by using integratedSecurity=true, I no longer needs username or password, but do I need to set up sql server for that or just put it there like that?

Comment: If you want to use username and password then you need to set integratedSecurity=false. You should be able to create accounts in the SQL Server you have set up and assign them to schemas.